# Why isn't bash accepting my color coding?

Tags: bash, shell, colors

I've got a simple code setup, but for whatever reason it refuses to operate how it should

```
#!/bin/bash
RED='\033[0:31m'
RESET='\033[0m'
```

Basically these are some simple color encodings

Next thing I have is

```
for file in ./dir/*.c; do
echo "File [${RED}$file${RESET}] has been launched"
```

My expected result would be

> File [myprogram.c] has been launched (while the name would be in red color)

Instead it just refuses to encode the color and dumps

> File [\033[0:31m] has been launched

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use `echo -e` instead of `echo`, also use `\033[0;31m`, not colon.

Comment: Don't use echo to print escape sequences. As there is no portable way to do it. Use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 4):

First because red is `'\033[31m'`. What you wrote means something else, read below.
Then, because the codes need to be interpreted.
This won't work:

```
$ red='\033[31m'

$ echo "${red}Hello"
```

But this would:

```
$ red='\033[31m'

$ echo -e "${red}Hello"
```

Or, you can assign the interpreted values to a variable:

```
$ red="$(echo -e '\033[31m')"
$ red="$(printf '\033[31m')"
```

Then the escapes don't need to be interpreted:

```
$ echo "${red}Hello"
```

What you wrote (besides using a colon where a semicolon should be) was setting the "boldness" of the foreground, or `0` for thin/light and `1` for bold/bright.

```
$ printf '\033[31mHello\033[0;31mHello\033[1;31mHello'
```

Also, `3x` is for foreground `4x` is for background:

```
$ printf '\033[31;42mHello\033[0;44;31mHello\033[1;43;31mHello\033[0m'
```

A full table could be printed with this:

```
$ printf "$(printf '%s' 033[{0,1}';'3{1..8}{';'4{1..8}mXXX,';'40m=OoO\\033[0m\\n}  )"
```

[image]

Comment: You should really use tput to get color codes for the shell.

Comment: @andlrc Why? Doesn't the code I wrote work in your system?

Answer (score 1):

> With tput

```
#!/bin/bash
red=$(tput setaf 1)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
for file in ./dir/*.c; do
 echo "File [${red}$file${reset}] has been launched"
done
```

> with printf

```
#!/bin/bash
RED='\033[0;31m'
RESET='\033[0m'
for file in ./dir/*.c; do
 printf  "File [${RED}$file${RESET}] has been launched"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. Red color code is `[031m`. The ASCII codes always start with an escape character, octal 33: `\033`. Thus, to start printing red text join the two sequences: `\033[031m`.

I find [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) post very helpful. In particular, the author recommends to use `tput` instead of the hard-coded values, and I agree with him.

**Example**

```
die() {
    local message="$1"
    : ${message:=Aborted}

    # See info bash BASH_SOURCE, info bash FUNCNAME, info bash BASH_LINENO
    printf '%s at %s:%s line %d\n' \
      "$message" ${BASH_SOURCE[1]} ${FUNCNAME[1]} ${BASH_LINENO[0]} >&2

    exit 1
}

# See man 1 tput, man 5 terminfo.
red=$(tput setaf 1) || die
noattr=$(tput sgr0) || die

# If tput is unavailable (very unlikely), use the hardcoded values as follows.
# The ANSI codes always start with the escape character (octal 33).
#esc='\033'
#red="${esc}[031m"
#noattr="${esc}[0m"

# %b causes printf to expand backslash escape sequences. See info bash printf.
printf '%b%s%b\n%s\n' "$red" 'red text' "$noattr" 'normal text'
```

Note the use of `printf`. [Don't use `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) in new software.